# stored procedures in dreamweaver using php

Tags: php, database, dreamweaver

I am making a site and I wondered is there a way to make stored procedures in dreamweaver so that it communicates with mysql (phpmyadmin)..like it is done in visual studio 2010 where you can create stored procedures that communicate with sql server 2005/2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver and php is a completly different world from .NET my friend. MySQL does support stored procedure, but it's a completly different language from T-SQL. Further more, note that stored procedures look like something that happen on your website but it's all SQL server side...

To use stored procedures, you can learn on the mysql website how to call them and how to create them, i don't know how though, i kinda never use stored procedures in PHP, never needed them IMO.

Good luck